# Why is 挺 used as measure word for machine guns?

Tags: measure-word

I recently noticed that the word 挺 (which I know mainly as an intensifier) also is the measure word for 機槍, machine guns. Now machine guns are a fairly recent invention, so I am wondering: Is it known who chose this measure word for them and why?

Comment: bkrs：挺 I v.
1) stick/bulge out
2) endure
你能挺多久？ How long can you endure?
3) slang deal with; handle
II b.f.
1) erect; firm (笔挺)
2) distinguished; standing out (英挺)
III adv.
very; rather; quite
IV m.
for machine guns (frequency rank) #778

Comment: @user6065  please, what is bkrs ?

Comment: suggestion: search web using "bkrs"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

挺，表数量，用于条状物。

As a measure word, 挺 refers to something that is long.

In《太平御览》卷八三五，it says 壶中大钱一千，以通九泉之路，**蜡烛一挺**，以照七尺之尸。

In modern Chinese, 一挺蜡烛 is no longer commonly used.

Comment: Ah, so I guessed wrong: instead of somebody deciding to use it as a new measure word for machine guns, it is an old measure word that no longer has any other uses. That makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: @Kusma I have never thought about this deeply before you asked, thank you too!